# Unable to correlate Session id

Tags: jmeter

Unable to correlate session id using 'Regular Expression Extractor' in Jmeter

Steps

1.Recorded a UI through Blazemeter tool and opened that jmx file in Jmeter.

2.Added View Result Tree

3.Execute the script

Now session id is getting displayed in 'http request sampler',but not able to correlate it using 'Regular Expression Extractor'

https://xxxxxx.jsp?sid=00D1D0000008cuo%21AREAQGjkXGsXgyrRwsAnN2O0m0oiecGwTUd1n5zFPMIRRQVnu2RZnynMF5eTBhAzGRsQnWIzcdapD4GCysXbOA6JtSRi69Pq&apv=1&allp=1&cshc=D000000FAHdD0000008cuo&display=page

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform the correlation of this value: `sid=00D1D0000008cuo%21AREAQGjkXGsXgyrRwsAnN2O0m0oiecGwTUd1n5zFPMIRRQVnu2RZnynMF5eTBhAzGRsQnWIzcdapD4GCysXbOA6JtSRi69Pq`

You can do this using [HTTP URL Re-writing Modifier](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-http-url-re-writing-modifier), the only thing you will need to do is to provide `sid` as the "Session Argument Name"

[image]

---

If you want to use "classic" correlation using Regular Expression Extractor the relevant regex would be something like `sid=(.+?)&`

Demo:

[image]

Just make sure to apply the extractor to **URL** field:

[image]